# What is the maximum timeout for executing a payment using the PayPal REST API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have transactions in the LIVE area of our developer console, however, they are only payment approvals, not executed payments.  I am trying to retrieve and execute payments that are listed as LIVE transactions however it appears that the payments no longer exist.  When trying to access the payment, I get an INVALID_RESOURCE_ID.

However, if I use an ID that is an executed payment, I can get a valid response.
i.e. using POSTMAN and accessing a URL like:
https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-79813274XD290572UKYNLZ5A

Will retrieve the JSON response I expect.

But a non executed payment will get.

```
{
  "name": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
  "message": "The requested resource ID was not found",
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
  "debug_id": "2bf3983d24c5d"
}
```

Is there any way to execute payments on payments that only when through the approval process and not execution after the fact?  And if so, what is the window?

Answer (score 0):

If you receive PayPal payments, they will come back as a Preapproved payment that needs to be executed. They are executed via the API call Execute:

POST /v1/payments/payment/{Payment-Id}/execute

You can see more information here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment

Comment: How do I get the payerId if I only have the information from the live transactions dashboard and I am no longer in the workflow?  In other words, I only have the preapproved payment response JSON that is in the dashboard and not the actual response back which has the PayerId in the URL.

Comment: You cannot get the PayerID, but you can get the PaymentID which is what you need to execute the payment. It is listed under "body" -> "id" in the response

Comment: Hi Robert - thanks again for the reply... but it does say in the documentation that the payer_id is required.


`payer_id string The ID of the Payer, passed in the return_url by PayPal. Required.`

Comment: Hi Robert,
I have tried to execute a payment without a payerID and I get a null reference.

Also recall the original post was that I can't retrieve a payment that was only preapproved and not executed.  I was hoping to retrieve the payment object so that I could access the child payer object.

It just seems like it is not possible to do it outside of the workflow using only the information provided in the LIVE transaction view of the dashboard.

Comment: Hi Circle8, I'm sorry. You are correct. You can get this information using GET /v1/payments/payment/{Payment-Id}

Comment: Hi Robert,
That doesn't seem to be a resolution either since it appears you can retrieve the object on already executed payments and not those that were **only** preapproved without execution.  If you try it on a preapproved but not executed payment, you get the INVALID_RESOURCE_ID error I posted above.